# How to print list with newline python?

Tags: python

I have a list like this.

```
[['Year', 'Salary', 'Yearly Income'], 
 [2, 2500, 30000], 
 [2, 3000.0, 36000.0], 
 [2, 3600.0, 43200.0], 
 [2, 4320.0, 51840.0], 
 [2, 5184.0, 62208.0], 
 [2, 6220.8, 74649.6]
]
```

I need print Like this

[image]

How can I do that in Python?

here is my code

```py
work_experience = 0
year = 1
cnt =0
basic_salary = 2500
salary_list = [["Year", "Salary", "Yearly Income"]]


input_name = input("Please Enter Your Name: ")


print("Welcome ", input_name)

work_experience = int(input("How many years of work experience do you have? : "))

for years in range (int(work_experience / 2)):
    # calculate incremented salary after 2 years
    # Increment happens every 2 years with 20% and decimal precison of 2
    basic_salary = round(basic_salary + (basic_salary * 0.2), 2)

for years in range (6):
    # calculate yearly_income by multiplying current_salary with 12
    yearly_income = round((basic_salary * 12), 2)
    salary_list.append([year+1, basic_salary, yearly_income])
    # update current salary
    basic_salary = round(basic_salary + (basic_salary * 0.2), 2)

print(salary_list)
```

Comment: Could you consider using pandas?

Comment: Use two nested for loops to iterate over the elements of your list and print them however you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most simple version you can use string formatting to display your data:

```
print('{:<4}  {:<6}\t{:<13}'.format(*salary_list[0]))
for row in salary_list[1:]:
    print('{:<4}  {:<6.2f}\t{:<13.2f}'.format(*row))


Year    Salary     Yearly Income
2       2500.00    30000.00     
2       3000.00    36000.00     
2       3600.00    43200.00     
2       4320.00    51840.00     
2       5184.00    62208.00     
2       6220.80    74649.60
```

An alternative providing a lot of useful functions to work with data like that is pandas. (pip install pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(salary_list[1:], columns=salary_list[0])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for row in salary_list:
    print('\t'.join([str(_) for _ in row]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use format. Here is one generic (sort of) code.
It first computes the size of the fields (using maxSize, that computes
one size per column).
Then build a string formatter, containing one "{:*n*s}" per field, n being the size+1 of each field.
And then applies this format to each line.

```py
def printList(l):
    maxSize=[max(len(str(line[j])) for line in l) for j in range(len(l[0]))]
    strFormat=''.join(f"{{:{m+1}s}}" for m in maxSize)
    for line in l:
        print(strFormat.format(*[str(f) for f in line]))
```